# with statement yields "Invalid syntax" error in Python 2.4

Tags: python

I have some code written in Python 2.7 like so :

```
if (os.path.exists('/path/to/my/file/somefile.txt')):
        with open('/path/to/my/file/somefile.txt', 'r') as readfile:
                firstline = readfile.readline()
                return firstline
```

When I try to run this on a system that has python 2.4, I get and Invalid Syntax error:

```
with open('/path/to/my/file/somefile.txt', 'r') as readfile:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `with` statement doesn't exist in Python 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `with` doesn't exist, could you try this instead?

```
import os

if (os.path.exists('/root/testing/test123.txt')):
        readfile = open('/root/testing/test123.txt', 'r')
        teststr = readfile.readline()
        print teststr #or 'return' if you want that
```

Comment: Better to try to open the file then catch IOError; will avoid race conditions. See the file opening example here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'with' statement aka context managers in Python 2.4.

Python 2.4 is more than 10 years old.

Upgrade to Python 2.7 or 3.3.